# SSRS Local Report (VS 2012) C# Windows Application - Dynamic Report Background Image

Tags: reporting-services, background, visibility, watermark

I have a report in a Windows Application that supports a trial mode.

We would like the report to display a watermark when the trail is active, and I have approached this successfully by adding the watermark text as an image to the report background.  Which is not perfect as it should be on top,  but it is certainly good enough.

I have a small challenge though and I am sure it is simply lack of knowledge on my part.

I need to turn the watermark on and off, based on the trial status.

Is there a way that I can change background visibility in the report based on a parameter or programmatically?   or do I need switch the Image for a transparent one and load it as report data?  Any better ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally hide the image based on a parameter.

If you create a hidden boolean parameter, for example, ShowMe, and have it default to false. You can set it to true in your application.

Set the hidden expression of the image to - > =`Not Parameters!ShowMe.Value`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Can I do this on Report.BackgroundImage?  I cannot see where I would add the expression.

Comment: Set the expression of the BK image value to "" if you do not want the image to display.